# Possible number of endofunctors

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, category-theory

The discrete category with countably many objects and morphisms has uncountably many endofunctors (= the [number of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Natural_Number_Functions_are_Uncountable)).

Which categories with countably many objects and morphisms have only countably many endofunctors?

For example the category of graphs?

By which heuristic arguments could I tell?

Comment: The question is not specific enough.